# is there a way to import needed jquery without effecting site jquery

Tags: javascript

is there a way programically import jquery only effecting one div and I have a second question is there a way to import a stylesheet to only effect one div to

currently for css im doing:

```
var l = document.createElement("link");
l.rel = "stylesheet";
l.href = "url";
document.getElementById("id").appendChild(l);
```

but if I'm not mistaken that effects the rest of the document.

Comment: There is nothing you can do to make a stylesheet only apply to one element other than making sure the rules in that stylesheet only apply to one element.

Comment: "stylesheet to only effect one div" This is done in CSS alone. There is plenty of CSS rules to help you with that.

Comment: Can you expound on what you mean by "programmatically import jquery to only effect one div"? Either you import jQuery or you don't. Either your codebase has access to the jQuery functions or it doesn't. Some tricks can be used to help improve performance, like tree shaking or lazy loading, but if you're only going to use jQuery in one place, I would recommend just figuring out how to do it without jQuery - the DOM APIs aren't that hard to use.

Comment: @epascarello I agree this is the way to go if you have full access to the page, or want to leave it unmodified (for whatever reasons) - but I politely have to disagree on "there is nothing you can do" - see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Both is possible using a [shadowRoot](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ShadowRoot).**

This wont work in IE, have a look at: [canIUse (attachShadow)](https://caniuse.com/?search=attachShadow)

This may be useful if you dont want (or cannot) alter the target page.

You could use your own jQuery-Version for every shadowRoot without affecting your DOM.

### Working Example:

```js
const target = document.getElementById('target');
const shadowRoot = target.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});

// Add paragraph (global style does not apply)
const paragraph = document.createElement('p');
paragraph.innerHTML = '<ul><li>I get bold but not blue</li></ul>'
shadowRoot.appendChild(paragraph);

// Add Style (applies only for shadow)
const style = document.createElement('style');
style.innerHTML = 'li { font-weight: bold; }'
shadowRoot.appendChild(style);

// Add external js (like jquery) likewise
```

```css
li {
  color: #00F;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>I get blue but not bold</li>
</ul>
<div id="target"></div>
```